# How to have two registration forms in WooCommerce? one for regular customer and two for membership

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-subscriptions, woocommerce-memberships

As per subject line, I want to have two forms in my WordPress website that has a WooCommerce store integrated. I want one of the form(billing form) as a default and two for membership. I am using YITH WooCommerce Subscription plugin for subscription.

Please let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own regular form either in a page template and add create user processing code logic in there or using Gravity Form plugin with its User Registration add-on.

For subscriptions, you can set up the subscript products and when users go to the checkout place, WooCommerce Subscription plugin has the option in the backend to create users on buying products. I think it's checked by default. If not, go to the checkout tab of the WooCommerce settings.